# How to end this program when user press "Enter" instead of one space character?

Tags: c

Below program get user input till it encounters a one space.(program works with this) But I want the user to stop it when he hits "Enter" key only. So I changed

```
 (buffer[0] != '\0')
```

to

```
 (buffer[0] != '\n')
```

but this does not work. How can I achieve this? (I know that "Enter" means "\n")

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

int count = 0;
char buffer[80];

char *myDynamicArray[25];
int i = 0;
int k = 0;

puts("Enter integers, press space to end");

while ((i < 25) && (gets(buffer) != 0) && (buffer[0] != '\0'))
{
    if ((myDynamicArray[i] = (char *)malloc(strlen(buffer) + 1)) == NULL)
        return -1;
    strcpy(myDynamicArray[i++], buffer);

}

count = i;

for (k = 0; k < count; k++)
{
    printf("%s\n", myDynamicArray[k]);
}

getchar();

}
```

Comment: Sorry, but "Enter" does _not_ "mean" `\n`.

Comment: You can check for both `'\n'` and `'\r'`

Comment: Don't check for `'\n'` or `'\r'`.

Comment: What should I check? I am confused.

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but don't cast the return of `malloc`, and (though not strictly required here), you're not `free`-ing the allocated memory, which is considered bad practice

Comment: @Lyrk, your program already stops on a blank line and doesn't stop on a space, as Klas Lindback explains. The `gets` function gives you an empty string if the line was blank, and a non-empty string if it was not blank. The `gets` function does not transfer the `\n` into the buffer; and there should be no `\r` since `stdin` is a text stream.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current program stops it when the user hits "Enter" key only and it doesn't stop if you enter a single space.

`gets` removes the newline and doesn't store it in the buffer, so buffer[0] will equal '\0' with no input and  if you enter a space.

A few notes:

- Enable compiler warnings. Warnings give you hints on potential bugs.
- You are missing 2 `#include` files: `stdlib.h` and `string.h`.
- `gets` has been deprecated due to its unsafe nature visavi buffer overruns. Use `fgets` instead!

Comment: I enabled all compiler warnings in Visual Studio Express 2013 according to this article. Still does not give me any warning you mentioned. What should I do more?  http://mihai-nita.net/2010/05/10/changing-default-vs-warning-level/

Comment: My compiler (gcc in linux) warned me about missing declarations for malloc and strcpy. It is possible that stdio.h included with MSVC provides declarations for malloc and strcpy. For maximum portability you should #include stdlib.h and string.h explicitly.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck: pedantic side-note: `fgets` + blank line (only a `\n` char) does not return null, so using `fgets` would require the OP to check the value of `buffer[0] == '\0'` to detect an empty line. Ie: `while((fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin)) != NULL && buffer[0] != '\0')` is required

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the most *"traditional"*, basic approach I can think of would be to do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ( void )
{
    int c, i, j=0;
    char buffer[80], *dynArray[5];
    for (i=0;i<5;++i)
    {
        j = 0;
        while((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n' && j < 79)
            buffer[j++] = c;
        if (j == 0)
        {//an empty string was encountered!
            for (--i;i>-1;--i)
            {//use --i, because current i is not allocated yet!
                printf("Freeing memory containing \"%s\"\n", dynArray[i]);
                free(dynArray[i]);
            }
            return EXIT_SUCCESS;//exit program here, then
        }
        buffer[j] = '\0';//add NULL-char
        dynArray[i] = calloc(j, sizeof *dynArray[i]);//calloc to initialize memory
        if (dynArray[i] == NULL)
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        strcpy(dynArray[i], buffer);
    }
    //allow user to see a specific input string again:
    puts("Choose a string to see again [1-5], or enter q to proceed");
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != 'q')
    {
        c -= (1 + '0');//simple atoi trick
        if (c < 5 && c > -1)//input char is 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5
            printf("string %d: %s\n", c+1, dynArray[c]);
    }
    //q was fetched from stdin, clear buffer...
    while((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n');
    for (i=0;i<5;++i)
    {
        printf("free-ing memory containing: %s\n", dynArray[i]);
        free(dynArray[i]);
    }
    getchar();//press any key to continue...
    return 0;
}
```

You can play around with this as you see fit (splitting bits and pieces of this into functions and such)...
Here's a more usable example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int get_key( const int max )
{
    int c, r = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != 'q' && c != '\n')
    {
        c -= '0';
        if (c > -1 && c < 10)
        {
            if (r > 0)//suppose input was 22, r will be 2 on second iteration of loop
                r *=10;//multiply by 10, to get 20
            r += c;//add 2 == 22
        }//optionally add else, clean buffer and procede if r > 0
    }
    if (r > max || r == 0)//perhaps move to loop body
        r = -1;//out-of-bounds request = -2
    if (c == 'q')
    {
        r = 0;//stop = -1
        //clean buffer
        while (c != EOF && c != '\n')
            c = getchar();
    }
    return r-1;//subtract 1 to get array index (zero indexed)
}

int main ( void )
{
    int c, k, i;
    char buffer[80], *myDynamicArray[25];
    puts("Enter string");
    for (k=0;k<25;++k)
    {
        i=0;
        while((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n' && i < 79)
            buffer[i++] = c;
        if (i == 0)
            break;
        if (i == 79)
            while (c != EOF && c != '\n')
                c = getchar();//clean buffer
        buffer[i] = '\0';
        myDynamicArray[k] = calloc(i, sizeof *myDynamicArray[k]);
        if (myDynamicArray[k] == NULL)
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        strcpy(myDynamicArray[k], buffer);
    }
    printf("Choose which string you'd like to see again [1-%d], press q to quit\n", k);
    while ((c = get_key(k)) != -1)
        if (c != -2)
            printf("String %d: %s\n", c+1, myDynamicArray[c]);
        else
            printf("input must be in the 1 - %d range\n", k);
    for (i=0;i<k;++i)
    {
        printf("%s\n", myDynamicArray[i]);
        free(myDynamicArray[i]);
    }
    printf("Press any key to continue...");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: omg that was intense . Need time to grasp. Thanks for the nice reply.

Comment: @Lyrk: This code is still quite basic, and IMO, not very good. I've added a better example (one that can handle more than 10 strings of input, and can handle input like _"Choose a string to see again"_ followed by user input `12`

Comment: @Lyrk: if this is all your code does, then please do consider ditching `buffer` and just use a single stack variable like `lines[25][80]` or something. It's bound to be faster, less error prone and isn't likely going to deplete the stack any time soon :)